# SharePoint 2013 Date Range Filter on list using FilterFields and FilterOps

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, filter, ootb

I am working on a project in SharePoint 2013.

Currently I am trying to implement list view filtering using OOTB QueryString parameters.  I have found the following params have been working a treat when dealing with a single condition: FilterField1, FilterValue1, FilterOp1 etc

```
http://spsite/Lists/CustomList/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=FieldName&FilterValue1=FieldValue&FilterOp1=Gt
```

The hurdle I have hit is implementing a date range filter i.e. multiple conditions on a single field.  Articles I have read have said to use the following to get a date range working:

```
FilterField1=DateField&FilterValue1=2015-06-01&FilterOp1=Geq&FilterField2=DateField&FilterValue2=2015-06-30&FilterOp2=Leq
```

When I have applied this to my list URL it only honours the last condition i.e. Date is Less than or equal to 2015-06-30.

I swapped the order of the query string params and again honoured the last condition (this time it was greater than or equal to 2015-06-01).

Any suggestions on how I could get this working using the FilterField query string params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read recently that only a single condition is allowed per column so you need to add a calculated column which is just a copy of the date column and use the new column for the other end of your date range in the filter.